# Android - DialogFragment - When touch EditText, the keyboard shows up and hide before type

Tags: android, user-interface

i'm experiencing this problem on DialogFragment, with an input edit text box, when the dialog popup and you touch the text box for input the keyboard shows up and immediately hide, pushing up and down the pop up dialog. hence i cannt put in anything.

here is the dialogfragment code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.test.abc.testingapppay.R;
public class AlertCaptureItemQuantity extends DialogFragment {
   @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_quantity_prompt,null);
        final EditText quantity = (EditText)            view.findViewById(R.id.text_quantity);
        quantity.requestFocus();

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())

                .setView(view)
                .setTitle("Quantity")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
                        // val_quantity =Double.parseDouble(quantity.getText().toString());
                        Intent i = new Intent().putExtra("quantityEntered", quantity.getText().toString());
                        getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
                        if (quantity.getText().length() > 0) {
                            dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User cancelled the dialog
                        dismiss();
                    }
                }).create();
            }
    }
```

and the main call from main actvity

```
   AlertCaptureItemQuantity  AlertDialogItems= new AlertCaptureItemQuantity();
   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();//getFragmentManager();
  AlertDialogItems.show(fragmentManager.beginTransaction(),"items");
```

activity xml file for the dialog

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/text_quantity"
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image id dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aQw4.jpg)

Comment: Add this to your xml code for EditText `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`.

Comment: Hi Stanojkov Thanks, but still no luck! it is like the dialog is pushing out the keyboard. once touched goes up to give a room/space for the keyboard and then push the keyboard out of site.